# Can't get PELU or SineRelu activation function to work in keras with contribute module

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, activation-function

When I try to replace LeakyRELU or relu in a working coding with either SineRELU or PELU. I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: Unknown activation function:PELU

I'm using the `keras.contrib`. I attached example code. I have tried it in several peaces of code. Any method of implementing this would be appreciated.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LeakyReLU, UpSampling2D, Conv2D, Concatenate
from keras_contrib.layers import SineReLU
from keras.models import Model,load_model,  Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# Recommended method; requires knowledge of the underlying architecture of the model
from keras_contrib.layers import PELU

import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='PELU'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='PELU'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# Create your first MLP in Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=150, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: `PELU` and `SineRELU` are not located in the module `keras.layers` and therefore the error is thrown. You are importing `PELU` and `SineRELU`  layers from the `keras.contrib.layers` module. Use them as layers in the model like `model.add( SineReLU() )`

Answer (score 2):

Just before answering, I feel a bit amazed to have found a question about the SineReLU on Stack Overflow. I'm the guy who wrote the function. :)

So, the custom activation on Keras are called advanced activations and they extend the Layer class, found under `keras.layers`. After some changes in the Keras Contrib packaging, prior to their 1.0 release preparations, the SineReLU, along with other advanced activations, moved to the `keras_contrib.layers.advanced_activations` package.

But answering your question, to use the `SineReLU`, or any other advanced activation, please do:

```
from keras_contrib.layers.advanced_activations.sinerelu import SineReLU
...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape = (784,)))
model.add(SineReLU())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
...
```

You can also fine tune the SineReLU. To know more about its `epsilon` parameter, check the documentation here.

I also wrote a Medium story about it and gave a couple of talks at conferences about the function. You can find more resources here:

https://medium.com/@wilder.rodrigues/sinerelu-an-alternative-to-the-relu-activation-function-e46a6199997d

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not passing the activations correctly, the string format for the `activation` parameter of a layer only applies for built-in activations, not custom ones.

Additionally since the PELU has parameters, it is implemented as a layer, not as a standalone activation function, so you need to add it like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8))
model.add(PELU())
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(PELU())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```